# XPath multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, xpath

I'm scraping a website that's mostly table based. I have `<tr>` tags that each represent a category and `<td>` tags inside these that represent properties of the category.

Using Xpath I get the `<tr>` fine but with all the `<td>` info inside it bunched as one string:

```
$html_string = file_get_contents('testpage.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$context_nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@id="category"]/tr[not(starts-with(@id, "category"))]');
```

And can each get `<td>` fine but with no retrospective reference to the category with:

```
$context_nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@id="category"]/tr[not(starts-with(@id, "category"))]/td');
```

What I would like to do later is be able to reference the properties of each category. I presumed I could do so with $context_nodes[2] etc., thinking that the array it created was a multidimensional string array. This doesn't seem to be the case.

How would I go about creating an array from the xpath info where I can grab a property of a category based on identifying what category I specifically want. E.g. train[1][2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is on the right lines. PHP (or, rather, libxml) retains a reference to the context the nodes you selected were returned from, allowing you to do precisely what you need in your case.

**XML**

```
<root>
    <cat name="category 1">
        <prop>prop 1.1</prop>
        <prop>prop 1.2</prop>
    </cat>
    <cat name="category 2">
        <prop>prop 2.1</prop>
        <prop>prop 2.2</prop>
    </cat>
</root>
```

**PHP**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$props = $xml->xpath('cat/prop');
foreach($props as $prop) {
    //let's go back up...
    $parent_cat = $prop->xpath('parent::*/@name');
    echo '<p>'.$prop.' (property of '.$parent_cat[0].')</p>';
}
```

Notice how we navigate back up the tree, from the point of the `prop` node, to reference the parent category. Not sure if this is what you meant but hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, thankyou very much. I had solved this using a much longer method so it's great to know there's a more straightforward method built in. Thanks!